# How to store the positions of an element in string in a dictionary (Python)?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to get all the positions (indexes) of an element in a string and store them in a dictionary.

This is what I've tried:

```
string = "This is an example"       
test = {letter: pos for pos, letter in enumerate(string)}
```

But this only gives the last position of the letter. I'd like all positions, desired output:

```
test["a"]
{8, 13}
```

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you are overwriting the dictionary values. For example,

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> my_dict['my_val'] = 1 # creating new value
>>> my_dict
{'my_val': 1}
>>> my_dict['my_val'] = 2 # overwriting the value for `my_val`
>>> my_dict
{'my_val': 2}
```

If you want to keep all values for a key you can use a list along with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method .

```
>>> print(dict.setdefault.__doc__)
Insert key with a value of default if key is not in the dictionary.
Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
>>>
>>> result = {}
>>> string = "This is an example"
>>> 
>>> for index, value in enumerate(string):
...     result.setdefault(value, []).append(index)
... 
>>> result["a"]
[8, 13]
```

Comment: But now the result is a list, but I'd like a dictionary

Comment: @pythonR I don't understand your statement. Here `result` is a dictionary and `result['a']` is a list

Comment: @pythonR in your given desired output, you wrote `{8, 13}`--- this isn't a dictionary, it is a set. If you really want to keep them in a set, then just use `{}` instead of `[]` in the above answer, and replace `append` with `add`. I would recommend using a list though, like the answer does.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM It would be nice to explain the original problem and what is done in the solution, instead of just dropping the code.

Answer (score -1):

## FOR LIST

### Creating a dictionary with the keys being the characters in the input_string and the characters being the

### indices of the characters in the input_string.

```
output = {}
```

### Creating a input_string variable called `input_string` and assigning it the character `"This is an example"`

```
input_string = "This is an example"
```

### Iterating through the input_string and assigning the index of the character to `index` and the character

### to `character`.

### `output.setdefault(character, [])` is checking if the key `character` exists in the dictionary `output`. If it does not exist, it will create the key `character` and assign it the character `[]`. If it does exist, it will return the character of the key `character`. Then, `.append(index)` will append the character of `index` to the character of the key `character`.

```
for index, character in enumerate(input_string):
    output.setdefault(character, []).append(index)
```

### Desired Output

```
output["i"]
[2, 5]
```

---

## In SORT CODE BE LIKE:-

```
output = {}

input_string = "This is an example"

for index, character in enumerate(input_string):
    output.setdefault(character, []).append(index)
```

## FOR DICT/SET

---

### Creating a dictionary with the keys being the characters in the input string and the values being

### the indices of the characters in the input string.

```
output = {}

input_string = "This is an example"

for index, character in enumerate(input_string):
    output.setdefault(character, set()).add(index)
```

Comment: Bro, What a detailed Explanation